# How to replace characters in a string if they match 1 string but not another string?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string

I have two JSON values, I need JSON value A to be parsed at the same time value B is parsed without interfering with eachother, and still be able to be parsed.

A 
`{\"\"Protestant\"\":[...]}]` 
after parsing should be `{'"Protestant"':[...]}`

and B
`{\"\":[...]]`
after parsing should be `{"":[...]}`

While this is what I would want if I was not parsing, It Is not what I want before parsing. (as json sees " as the end of the string and gives an error with the P)

I cant hard code to fix this as this problems shows up with other things than just Protestant

My Code

```
response.data.replace(`{\\"`, `{"'`).replace('\\":', `'":`);
```

While I know that I can do this by

```
resonse.data.replace(`{\\"\\":`,'{RANDOMSTRING:');
```

and using that RANDOMSTRING as a placeholder while I change A's strings, but was wondering if there was a less gimmiky way of doing so.

This is what im getting back (which isn't parseable)

A = ""Protestant"", and B = "".

Is there anyway to do this by looking for `{\"\"` but not `{\"\":` ?

Comment: Did you tried `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: try [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), e.g. `let parsed = JSON.parse(response.data); console.log(parsed);`

Comment: Dump a before and after literal strings on your question, them maybe some answers will appear, who knows. Magic this is not !!!!!

Comment: Agreed, parse it; just wondering - as simple as [`{\\"\\"(?!:)`](https://regex101.com/r/CxSyeY/1) this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved by using the option when a function supplied to `someString.replace` instead of new value.
This function will get matched string as first parameter. So in your function you can check value to be replaced for match of second expression, and return incoming value unchanged if it matches your second expression.

Take look for documentation and examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Note: If you have control over the source of data you parsing, it may require a patch. According to data samples you provide, it looks as that data source produces really broken JSON, like double quotes etc.

Comment: The data can't be fixed as it is a census and for integrity it can not be changed. I'll look into the options thing though, thank you.

Comment: Please keep updated on your issue - whether my advice helped to get it working, and if so, please mark my reply as an answer for question.